# How to prove that $\sum_\limits{x=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^2a^x}{x!}$ is equal to $\left(a^2 + a\right)\!e^a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

It comes from the Poisson's distridution.
No ideas how to solve it.

The original is $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{k^{2}\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda} = \lambda^{2}+\lambda$

Comment: The question does not seem to be correct. Are you missing a limit? Or any other input?

Comment: @Sam, sum ....., x from 0 to infinity

Comment: @Sam In what sense? The sum indeed converges to that result.

Comment: @Angelo I'm afrain you're confusing the people over here. Sam is not the one who asked the question.

Comment: sorry, first time asking a question here. About the it. I have never dealt with such series. This is from the book "An Introduction to Probability Theory". It is not a task, i am just solving problems for myself

Comment: @Тима, if you do not write in your question which attempts you did, moderators will close your question very soon and suspend the account of everyone tries to help you. Please, write more context in your question. At the moment, two moderators have decided to close your questions and probably will close the accounts of the users who have answered your question. You can avoid it by writing more context in your question !

Comment: @Angelo ... Answering a low-quality question will not get the answerer's account closed.  If done repeatedly, on many different questions, it may merit a suspension.

Comment: @GEdgar, I know people whose accounts were suspended for a month o for a year because of answering low-quality questions. So, I know for a fact that it merits not just one day of suspension but much more.

Comment: @Тима at first there was no summation

Comment: @Тима, I told you moderators would close your question.

Comment: @Angelo, okey, no problem, i will be more attentive next time, sorry

Comment: @Тима, do not say sorry to me but to people who answered your low-quality question and for that reason their accounts may be suspended by moderators.

Comment: @Angelo, low-quality question is simple question or the question with no attempts to solve?

Comment: @Тима, I think you need to read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/771461

Comment: @Angelo, oh, i understand and respect the rules here. Thanks for the link

Comment: @Тима, you are welcome.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It can be proved straightforwardly.

First of all notice that $\dfrac{x^2}{x!} = \dfrac{x}{(x-1)!}$ hence your sum reduces to

$$\sum_{x = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x a^x}{(x-1)!}$$

Now another trick:

$$\dfrac{x}{(x-1)!} = \dfrac{(x-1+1)}{(x-1)!} = \dfrac{1}{(x-2)!} + \dfrac{1}{(x-1)!}$$ hence the sum is split into two trivial sums:

$$\sum_{x = 2}^{+\infty} \frac{a^x}{(x-2)!} + \sum_{x = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{a^x}{(x-1)!}$$

I'm rather sure that you already have met them, in your analysis course. Then you will easily remember that those are nothing but the exponential sums:

$$\sum_{x = 2}^{+\infty}\frac{a^x}{(x-2)!} = a^2 e^a$$

$$\sum_{x = 1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a^x}{(x-1)!} = a e^a$$

Which concludes the proof. (I bet you are able to show the latter results.)

Comment: Kurt, you should write $\sum_\limits{x=1}^\infty$ or $\sum_\limits{x=2}^\infty$ instead of $\sum_\limits{k=0}^{+\infty}$.

Comment: @Angelo I'm so used to the $k$ index... Thank you!

Comment: Kurt, you should also pay attention to write correctly the first value of the index in every sum, indeed it is *not* $0$.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't find the similar question on google, until i realized to search here with the latex-formulas. So, i hurried a lot and this question have to be banned. About series, i forgot that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n}}{n!}$ is taylor series for e^x vice versa

Comment: I would like to know who is the douche who downvoted a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{%
\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}{x^{2}a^{x} \over x!}} =
\pars{a\,\totald{}{a}}^{2}\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}{a^{x} \over x!} =
\pars{a\,\totald{}{a}}^{2}\expo{a}
\\[5mm] = & \
a\,\totald{}{a}\pars{a\expo{a}} =
a\pars{\expo{a} + a\expo{a}} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\pars{a^{2} + a}\expo{a}}}
\end{align}